# Firebase - How do I watch a list of objects for change using "on"?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

How do I watch a list of objects for change using "on"?

I have a list of profiles and want to watch this list to check if a new object is added or a profile is updated. So any change to the list.

Current code attempt:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://markng2.firebaseio.com");          
var refProfiles = ref.child('profiles');

refProfiles.on('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
      //Change has occurred in the list of profiles.
});
```

Here is an image of my Firebase Realtime Database:

[image]

Comment: I have updated above to show my code. @CodeiSir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if a profile was added or a specific profile was changed, you're better off listening to Firebase's `child_` events:

```
  var ref = new Firebase("https://markng2.firebaseio.com");        
  var refProfiles = ref.child('profiles');

  refProfiles.on('child_added', function(dataSnapshot) {
      var profile = dataSnapshot.val();
      console.log('Profile added: ', profile);
  });

  refProfiles.on('child_changed', function(dataSnapshot) {
      var profile = dataSnapshot.val();
      console.log('Profile changed: ', profile);
  });
```

See for more information the [Firebase documentation on reading data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html).